# Do expired versions of a certificate get purged from Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Does Azure Key Vault purge expired versions automatically so it does not get returned from [get key versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/get-key-versions/get-key-versions)?

Background:

We plan to use Azure Key Vault certificates with a 2 month rotation. So, we will set ValidityInMonths to 2 and RenewAtNumberOfDaysBeforeExpiry to 3 or so. The reason for the short rotation is that it will be used for asymetric signing.

We need to make the public keys available from an API, so we will call [get key versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/get-key-versions/get-key-versions).

My concern is that the number of versions will keep growing every 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the process is not automatic. To permanently delete a secret First a user must delete the object, which puts it into the soft-deleted state. Second, a user must purge the object in the soft-deleted state. The purge operation requires additional access policy permissions.

Note: Soft delete is Enabled by by default.

You can find more information here  [Azure Key Vault soft-delete overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview)